# Реализация Mysql запросов в цикле.

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Сложилась следующая задача скрипту передается около 60 ти переменных по ним нужно сделать сортировку из таблици и вывести все совпадения. Естественно нужно решать этот вопрос циклом. Но запросы в цикле писать бы не хотелось. Подскажите функции как можно реализовать следующие условия. Берем одну переменную выбираем все совпадения и вытаскиваем их идентификатор дальше берем вторую переменную если она существует то из уже выбраных полей которые вернул первый запрос выполняем сортировку по второй переменной и тд.

Comment: LEFT JOIN ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN насколько я знаю для реализации выборки из разных таблиц тут таблица одна.

Comment: если у вас все данные в одном таблице , и запрашиваемые поля одинаковые в запросе *select* можно и *union* - ом.

    select * from table where field1=$var1
    union
    select * from table where field2=$var2.
    etc;

Comment: нет немного не то

Comment: >LEFT JOIN насколько я знаю для реализации выборки из разных таблиц тут таблица одна// 

Одну таблицу можно джойнить саму на себя.

    Select `mt1`.`field1` from `my_table` as `mt1` left join `my_table` as `mt2` on `mt1`.`field2` = `mt2`.`field2`

Answer (score 1):

Именно циклом. Лучше сформировать один раз запрос и получить нужные данные, чем вручную фильтровать данные. тем более по 60 полям. Представьте, что вашему фильтру соответствует одна запись или вообще ни одной, а вы последовательно будете перебирать 100500 записей соответствующих только первой переменной, потом 100500 для второй переменной и т.д. а последняя переменная скажет, что ни одна из 100500 не подходит.

Пример формирования where clause (дословно так делать не надо, просто для пояснения смысла):

```
$where = "";
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  if ($v!="")
    $where.="AND "+$k+" = '"+$v+"'";
...
```

выполняете один раз этот запрос и получаете сразу нужные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Может так? запрос формируете динамически на основании переменных ?

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table where field1=$var1) order by field1, field2 ...
```

единственно что - Вам не проверить существуют те или иные поля в одном запросе - это надо наверное проверить всё предварительно, а потом формировать запрос по существующим полям.